# Using tile server in Leaflet, how to find tile server urls?

Tags: leaflet, arcgis-rest-api

https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/rest/services/lands/BLM_Natl_SMA_Cached_without_PriUnk/MapServer/7

This is the info I want in a tile layer but I don’t know what URL to use.

Can someone explain how I can generate the URL for Leaflet?

I am trying to find mapserver urls for the following maps:

https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/rest/services/lands

[image]

I believe arc-gis has the maps but I cannot find the actual tile urls to use.

Comment: What have you tried? - here is one example https://opengislab.com/blog/2018/2/4/creating-simple-leaflet-web-map

Comment: I've tried nothing because I have no idea what the url would be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overlay BLM map in leafletjs?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/430340/how-to-overlay-blm-map-in-leafletjs)

Comment: It does show the url but what I'm asking is looking at the arc-gis site, how do I figure out the url of their maps? It doesn't say anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use URLs for the *WMS* or *WMTS* links from the  `ArcGIS REST Services Directory` pages.

Looking at https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/rest/services/lands/BLM_Natl_SMA_Cached_without_PriUnk/MapServer

The WMS link is for the GetCapabilities response:

> https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/services/lands/BLM_Natl_SMA_Cached_without_PriUnk/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

and you will need just the URL minus query parameters for Leaflet:  *https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/services/lands/BLM_Natl_SMA_Cached_without_PriUnk/MapServer/WMSServer?*

For WMTS you have two options depending on whether you want to use *KVP* or *'RESTful'* options.

You need to look at the GetCapabilities response to get your options

> https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/rest/services/lands/BLM_Natl_SMA_Cached_without_PriUnk/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml

*KVP* use: *https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/rest/services/lands/BLM_Natl_SMA_Cached_without_PriUnk/MapServer/WMTS?*

*'RESTful'* use:
*https://gis.blm.gov/arcgis/rest/services/lands/BLM_Natl_SMA_Cached_without_PriUnk/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/*

Comment: Can you provide example code?

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318885/wmts-in-leaflet-cant-make-this-code-work